# What's the widest two-by size for a door frame I can use without warping becoming an issue?

Tags: doors, framing, door-frame, lumber

In order to be able to connect the outside (brick/masonry) and inside (lumber framing) structural elements, I need to use 2x10, anything shallower won't do. However, I'm reluctant to use lumber that wide as, in my experience, the wider it is (the width in 2xX being X), the more prone to warping it gets and I certainly don't want that for my entry door frame.

Is 2x10 okay to frame an entry door? Is my observation about the relationship between width and warping correct?

Comment: You might sketch out what you're doing for clarity. I'm having trouble picturing it. Is it just a rough-opening liner? You might use OSB lumber or microlam for stability, or just sandwich two layers of 3/4" plywood or OSB.

Comment: Answer below is good, but if you can't find good wood, can you do a jamb extension in 2x?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct for the most part if buying what is in stock at big box.   However if you have a local lumberyard that can get you something comparable to kiln dried SPF, I have never had an issue - or maybe 1 issue in 20 years.

I do recognize your statement though because if I do buy 2x10/12s from big box half of them will go back with a few days - I way over buy because of this.   If you are worried about them warping after install then you should cross block the gap every foot or so and brace it in.

I have had to do many many doors with 10by lumber.   I just make sure I buy good wood from lumberyard and get it installed within a day or two of buying.   I am not sure really what alternatives you have because I am assuming the door is load bearing.  I mean you could go with an LVL that is rated for vertical install and have them rip it to 10" - this seems to be way way overdoing it but just giving you a "perfect" option.

Comment: LVL is better but I usually use 2x with some plywood to get the correct thickness never had a problem with that.+